# form Data set values from web service response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to set table values from webservice response.
Iam getting my web service response like this.but if he response is like this means it is not getting set there.This response can be dynamic.

```
0:{name: "image.png", base64: "iVBORw"}
1:{name: "download.png", base64: "iVBO"}
2:{name: "test-animation.gif", base64: "R0lGODlhLAEs"}
```

How can i change it to??

```
[["image.png", "iVBORw"],["download.png", "iVBO"],[test-animation.gif", "R0lGODlhLAEs"]]
```

here it is  what iam trying

```js
$.cordys.ajax({
     method: "somewebservice",
     namespace: "Package",
     parameters: {
      emailid:mailidvalue
     },
     dataType: '* json',
      success: function (result) { 
      output=result;
      bodycontent=output["data"]["body"];
 var attachvalue=result.data.tuple;

    $('#attachmenttable').DataTable( {
        "data": attachvalue,
        columns: [
            { title: "File Name" },
            { title: "Base64" }
        ]
    } );
                       },
     error: function(err){
      console.log(err);
     }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a 1-1 mapping between what you are given and what you desire, therefore use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/).

```js
var given = {
  0: {
    name: "image.png",
    base64: "iVBORw"
  },
  1: {
    name: "download.png",
    base64: "iVBO"
  },
  2: {
    name: "test-animation.gif",
    base64: "R0lGODlhLAEs"
  }
};

var desired = Object.keys(given).map(function(key) {
  return [ given[key].name, given[key].base64 ];
});

console.log(desired);
```

```js
var given = {
  0: {
    name: "image.png",
    base64: "iVBORw"
  },
  1: {
    name: "download.png",
    base64: "iVBO"
  },
  2: {
    name: "test-animation.gif",
    base64: "R0lGODlhLAEs"
  }
};

var desired = $.map(given, function (value, key) {
  return [[ given[key].name, given[key].base64 ]];
});

console.log(desired);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```